# difference behaviour for generic method within generic class and for generic method within non-generic class

Tags: java, generics, erasure

I investigate generic behaviour

I noticed that:

```
public class Hohol1 {
    public class My<T> {
        public <E> void test(Collection<E> es) { System.out.println("Collection<E>");
        }

        public void test(List<Integer> integerList) {
            System.out.println("List<Integer>");
            for (Integer integer : integerList) {
                System.out.println(integer);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        My my1 = new Hohol1().new My();
        my1.test(new ArrayList<String>() { {add("1");} });
    }
}
```

code above returns

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at GenericsTest.Hohol1$My.test(Hohol1.java:22)
    at GenericsTest.Hohol1.main(Hohol1.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

But if I make `My` non-generic so

```
  public class Hohol1 {
        public class My/*deleted generic type T*/ {
             ....
        }
     }
```

this code returns `Collection<E>`

It is surpised behaviour for me and I don't understand why it created so.

What Do you think about it?

**P.S.** I use double brace initialization for laconic

Comment: @durron597 Did you read my question?  please read one more time and compare with yours

Comment: You are correct, my mistake. Close vote retracted

Answer (score 3):

First, when you are using the *raw* form of the inner class `My`, everything in the class, including unrelated specified type parameters such as the method parameter `List<Integer> integerList` act as if their own type erasure were in place, e.g. `List integerList`.

However, you pass in an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList` (effectively just an `ArrayList`) of `String`s.  The most specific method that applies is `test(List<Integer> integerList)`, because it's viewed as `List`, which your `ArrayList` certainly is.  Everything still runs until the enhanced `for` loop that attempts to print `Integer`s, but it can't convert a `String` such as `"1"` to an `Integer`, so you get the `ClassCastException`.

But if you make `My` non-generic, then the type of the parameter `integerList` is not erased.  The compiler then can see that `List<Integer>` doesn't match, but `Collection<E>` does match, so `test(Collection<E> es)` matches and `"Collection<E>"` is printed.

The reason is specified in the [JLS, Section 4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> More precisely, a raw type is defined to be one of:
>
> - The reference type that is formed by taking the name of a generic type declaration without an accompanying type argument list.
>
> ...

and

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

The reasoning is also given:

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types.

Comment: you just reward my question. I understood it. I don't know why so?

Comment: Why if I use Raw class I cannot use generic method declared within this class?

Comment: It's for backwards compatibility.  I've added to my answer with a JLS link and quotes.